# Picking up health doesn't change the players stats

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a player with 10 health. each time he gets hit he loses 1 health. The difference can be seen within the health bar. To give the player a chance to survive against waves of enemies I tried to recreate Health pickup.

I made the code so that the player gets healed, so far it triggers when the player walks over the icon, BUT for some reason, the player does NOT get healed?

To make use of all this I have 2 documents of code.

The first one underneath is the code added on the health pickup

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HealthPickup : MonoBehaviour
{
    Health health;

    public float healthBonus;

    void Awake()
    {
      health = FindObjectOfType<Health>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
      if(other.GetComponent<Player>() == null)
        return;

      if(health.health < health.maxHealth)
      health.health = health.health + (int)healthBonus;
      {
      Destroy(gameObject);
      }
    }
}
```

The following code is the code for the players health.

```
    [Header ("Max/Starting Health")]
    public int maxHealth;
    [Header ("Current Health")]
    public int health;

void Start () {
        health = maxHealth;
    }

    public bool TakeHeal (int amount) {
        if (dead || health == maxHealth)
            return false;

        health = Mathf.Min (maxHealth, health + amount);

        if (OnTakeHealEvent != null)
            OnTakeHealEvent.Invoke();


        return true;
    }
```

As you can see underneath I set the bonus health to 3. Adding 3 health towards the player when he collides with the object.
[image: Adding health]

As you can see the player has a total of 10 health. I try to reduce the health ingame and collide with the object. Yet no health is added towards the user.
[image: Player health]

As you can see the player has now 7 health (3.5 bars)
[image: Player health]

When I walk over the healthbar the players health (7) still stays at the same number. Even tho the collider and destroying of the object fully function.
[image: Player health]

Damage player function

```
    protected virtual void Awake () {
        if (Owner == null) {
            Owner = gameObject;
        }
    }

    public virtual void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {           
        Colliding (collider);
    }

    public virtual void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collider)
    {           
        Colliding (collider);
    }

    protected virtual void Colliding(Collider2D collider)
    {
        if (!isActiveAndEnabled) {
            return;
        }

        // if what we're colliding with isn't the target tag, we do nothing and exit
        if (!collider.gameObject.CompareTag(TargetTag)) {
            return;
        }

        var health = collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Health>();

        // If what we're colliding with is damageable / Has  health component
        if (health != null)
        {
            if(health.health > 0 && !health.invincible)
            {
                // Apply the Damage
                health.TakeDamage(DamageToCause);
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging this at all? The way your code exists in your question, I can't see a reason why it wouldn't work. Please give us some more information to help you.

Comment: I will provide more screenshots so everything is clearer for you guys give me a moment to do it

Comment: Where do you call `TakeHeal`?

Comment: Hi @MikeH in this case I haven't called TakeHeal at all but focussed on using the basic health function. I thought that would have been enough to see if it would add any HP at all.

Comment: Probably because you are invoking an action when Take Heal is called, and in your trigger you are just adding to the health rather then calling your TakeHeal function>

Comment: @Eddge but the problem is that I never call the TakeHeal function within my healthpickup document. All I wanted was to add the extra health on top of the health INT that was already on the character.

Comment: And that is were your problem is, in your healthpickup document.  show us how you deal damage to the player, then show us your healthbar.  I am willing to bet your healthbar doesnt check the players health in an update but instead registers for an event to update the bar.   If that is the case just adding your characters health wont update the health bar.

Comment: you aren't actually comparing current & max health when you destroy the pickup here: 
      `if(health.health < health.maxHealth)
      health.health = health.health + (int)healthBonus;
      {
      Destroy(gameObject);
      }`

it's certainly possible the `health` field in the pickup class refers to a different health component in the scene that has not been damaged (maybe on an enemy or object in the scene?), and the pickup gets destroyed anyway

Comment: @Ruzihm but he is still adding to the health in the case health is < maxhealth.

Comment: @Ruzihm but it is true that he could be adding it to a random health component in the scene.

Comment: @Eddge I will add a picture stating how the player gets damaged. Because the damage function does work with the health.health function.

Comment: @mafiaf try this:

    `void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
      if(other.GetComponent<Player>() == null)
        return;

      health = other.GetComponent<Health>();
      if (health.health.TakeHealth(healthBonus)){
       Destroy(gameObject);
      }
    }`

Comment: @mafiaf you are calling the TakeHealth function in there.  which helps to further prove you are doing something different in your heal script,  I would just do `health.TakeHealth((int)healthBonus);`  instead of your `health.health = health.health + (int)healthBonus;`

Comment: @Ruzihm you are right! Following your code has worked the only problem is that the player gets overhealed. Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: @mafiaf clamp it.

Comment: @Eddge do you have any form of documentation for that? I am fairly new to c# and unity so everything I learn is off documentations. Or if you can provide me with some code that would be very helpfull!

Comment: @mafiaf Ruzhim answer should solve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't guaranteeing that the `Health` instance you are modifying/checking is the same as what is attached to your player. So, when a collision with a `Player` occurs, you should get the `Health` component from the `Player` that you are colliding with.

Also, you already check for overheal in `TakeHeal`, so you can just re-use that method:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.GetComponent<Player>() == null)
        return;

    health = other.GetComponent<Health>();

    if (health.TakeHeal((int)healthBonus))
    { 
        Destroy(gameObject); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried your code but I get the following error message " error CS1061: 'Health' does not contain a definition for 'TakeHealth' and no accessible extension method 'TakeHealth' accepting a first argument of type 'Health' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @Ruzihm ahh your right I just noticed it calls TakeDamage...  in the case of damaging a player, I usually combine my healing and damage functions haha

Comment: @Ruzihm I've tried this code, but in this case it doesn't trigger at all. Not even destroying the object. The first code you have provided - void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) { if(other.GetComponent<Player>() == null) return; health = other.GetComponent<Health>(); if (health.health.TakeHealth(healthBonus)){ Destroy(gameObject); } } - did work but in this case i got overhealed

Comment: @Ruzihm Thanks for your help! You have solved the issue haha since Need to add a (int) before the healthbonus also to take effect. Thanks everyone for your help!